# Project Reactor non-blocking logging with slf4j

Tags: java, reactive-programming, logback, spring-webflux, project-reactor

The `log()` method in `Flux.class` for Project Reactor mentions that if `slf4j` is available, it will be used. If you use a logger implementation like `logback` with slf4j, they are by default blocking, especially the write to file/disk part. The Reactor documents don't mention anything about this. Does anyone have thoughts/experience on this?
I think one option is to maybe setup logback as async. Are there any other options? Thanks!

Comment: At any rate, Java NIO is still blocking for files. See for example [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3955250/697630). So I don’t think that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is an answer to your question, but by using `reactor-logback` I assumed that I am logging asynchronously.

I added the following log configuration (logback-spring.xml example)

```
<!-- Wrap calls to the logger. -->
<appender name="asyncFile" class="reactor.logback.AsyncAppender">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</appender>
```

I found this information [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/tree/master/reactor-logback).

Comment: While the mentioned solution seems to be a working approach I changed to another appender in the meantime that does asynchroneous logging, too. Namely `ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender`.